# What are the rules for overload resolution in Swift for both functions and operators?

Tags: swift

How does the Swift 2.1 compiler determine which method or operator to call given a set of overloads at a given call site?

This question may conflate two issues: method overloads and operator overloads, but it seems at least superficially that they are related. Somehow they end up using different rules as I will demonstrate shortly.

```
class A{
}

class B: A {
}

func +(a:A, b:A){
  print("+1")
}

func +(a:A, b:B){
  print("+2")
}

func +(a:B, b:A){
  print("+3")
}

/*
func +(a:B, b:B){
  print("+4")
}
*/

A() + A() // prints +1
A() + B() // prints +1
B() + A() // prints +1
// B() + B() // will come back to this

func f(a: A, b: A){
  print("f1")
}

func f(a: B, b: A){
  print("f2")
}

func f(a: A, b: B){
  print("f3")
}

/*
func f(a: B, b: B){
  print("f4")
}
*/

f(A(), b: A()) // prints f1
f(B(), b: A()) // prints f2
f(A(), b: B()) // prints f3
// f(B(), b: B()) // will come back to this
```

The output from the various invocations of `f()` make sense. It seems that Swift uses similar overload resolution rules as Java where the 'most specific method' is chosen given a set of methods whose parameters are part of the same class hierarchy.

Given the code as-is, the outputs from the operator overloads all seem to call the first operator defined. The order of definition doesn't matter, if `+(A, A)` is put last it will still be called by all three invocations of +. Already this doesn't make sense to me. Why isn't `+(A, B)` called for the expression `A() + B()`?

Something strange happens when the function `+(B, B)` is uncommented out. All of a sudden the overloads work just like they did in the regular function definition case.

The full code is:

```
func +(a:A, b:A){
  print("+1")
}

func +(a:A, b:B){
  print("+2")
}

func +(a:B, b:A){
  print("+3")
}

func +(a:B, b:B){
  print("+4")
}

A() + A() // prints +1
A() + B() // prints +2
B() + A() // prints +3
B() + B() // prints +4
```

Without the definition of `+(B, B)` the expression `B() + B()` is an error because it is ambiguous whether to choose `+(A, B)` or `+(B, A)`. I am fine with that behavior. But why do `A()+B()` and `B()+A()` suddenly refer to the `+2` and `+3` operators respectively?

The regular function case does not behave this way. Given the 3 uncommented defintions of `f` as above the output is as expected, `f1`, `f2`, `f3` in order. When the definition of `f(B, B)` is uncommented the expression `f(B(), B())` works as expected and prints `f4`. The other expressions are unaffected.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: No, I made a bug on bugs.swift.org. https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-278